# What does the Google Maps Geocoding API return if querying a city?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am currently working on a research project where we use the Geocoding API to determine the coordinates of cities. Unfortunately, I do not understand how they define city or regions? Is there something like a geographic center. I read through the developer guidelines, but I couldn't find the answer.

Is their any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a set of two points that designee the approximately area of the city. (viewport)

It also returns the center of the area which you may be using (location)

Both are in the geometry object of the response.

more at : [google doc on place search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchResults)

Comment: Unfortunately, the R-package I am using does not provide such measures. (`ggmap::geocode()`). It seems that I've to write my own implementation. Thanks anyway!